# $\Theta(m \log m)=\Theta(m\log n)$ for every undirected graph.

Tags: graph-theory, asymptotics

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a undirected graph with $|V|=n, |E|=m$.
We have $\Theta(m \log m)=\Theta (m \log n)$.
My answer is yes because a undirected graph has at most $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ edges.
So the ratio $\frac{f(m,n)}{g(m,n)}$ and $\frac{g(m,n)}{f(m,n)}$ for $f(n)=m\log(\frac{n(n-1)}{2}), g(n)=m\log(n)$ are bounded for $m,n \to\infty$.
Is this correct?

Comment: Without more information about how $m$ and $n$ are going to infinity we can't conclude this. For example, we could have $m = \log n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you showed is $m \log m \in \mathcal{O}(m \log n)$.

For the other direction (i.e. $m \log n \in \mathcal{O}(m \log m)$) you need some lower bound on the number of edges (e.g. you only consider connected graphs).